# Como correr sites Node.js diferentes no mesmo servidor?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express.js

Tenho um servidor Linux e nesse servidor tenho vários sites hospedados, cada um com sua pasta e arquivos. Quero começar a usar o Node.js para criar as API's de cada site. Qual a melhor maneira de fazer isso?

Um processo e porta por cada site ou um único processo usando vhost, connect e cluster? Apache? nginx?

Comment: Entendo que o mais simples é checar o `Host:` do request, não precisa instalar nada a mais, é mera condição de entrada. Se precisar de muito mais complexidade, melhor mudar de tecnologia..

Answer (score 1):

você pode utilizar o NGINX como um proxy reverso na frente do NODEjs.

Nessa abordagem pode rodar diversos processos com o NODEJS, cada um em uma porta e configurar no NGINX um subdomínio para cada processos/API, sendo assim necessário apenas deixar a porta padrão HTTP liberada no servidor para acesso externo.

**Exemplo:**

Site: exemplo.com.br

 
API: api.exemplo.com.br -> NODEJS na porta 8888

SIte: exemplo2.com.br

API: api.exemplo2.com.br -> NODEJS na porta 9999

**Configuração do NGINX**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    index index.html;

    server_name exemplo.com.br www.exemplo.com.br;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html/exemplo.com.br;

    location / {
            try_files $uri /index.html;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name api.exemplo.com.br;

    location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8888;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    index index.html;

    server_name exemplo2.com.br www.exemplo2.com.br;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html/exemplo2.com.br;

    location / {
            try_files $uri /index.html;
    }
}


server {
    listen 80;
    server_name api.exemplo2.com.br;

    location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9999;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

http://www.devmedia.com.br/usando-nginx-como-proxy-reverso-e-diminuindo-o-consumo-do-servidor/21461

Comment: Mas eu vou usar essa solução para trabalhar com vários sites, logo, várias portas. Será que não fica meio inviável utilizar tantas portas assim? Acha essa solução melhor que usar um só processo node e tratar qual app usar pelo dns?

Comment: A multiplicidade de portas só vai ser um problema se você rodar mais que 50 mil sites num mesmo computador, e certamente isso não é uma boa ideia (50 mil instâncias de Node.js devem gastar memória à beça...)

Comment: Entendo, com certeza não vou rodar mais que 50 mil sites. Na sua opinião, epx, é melhor apostar em um processo para cada site do que em um só processo administrando tudo?